# Kubernetes - when specified in pvc "volumeMode: Block" NodePublishVolume is not called

Tags: kubernetes, storage

I am working on CSI driver and need to support block volume (in addition to filesystem we already have)

When specifying `volumeMode: Block` NodeStageVolume and NodePublishVolume are not called.

When removing `volumeMode: Block` and in POD change volumeDevices entry to volumeMounts it works fine

PV descriptiopn shown VolumeMode: Block 
Added featuregates BlockVolume=true,CSIBlockVolume=true in kube-apiserver.yaml

We are using k8s 1.14

Any idea what can be the reason or any suggestion how to investigate (e.g. which logs to see except node an controller)?

thank you

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvcraw67b
spec:
  volumeMode: Block
  storageClassName: sc67b
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: podraw67b
spec:
    containers:
       - name: fc-container
         image: fedora:26
         command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
         args: [ "tail -f /dev/null" ]      
         volumeDevices:
              - devicePath: /dev/block
                name: pvcrawvol67b
    volumes:
      - name: pvcrawvol67b
        persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvcraw67b
```

Comment: Its your local env or On-Prem? Did you trie describe pod and nodes? Did you see anything in `kubectl get events` or tried `journalctl -u kubelet`?

Comment: Which exactly cloud are you using? To clarify, you want to create your own driver, or you have issue with proper run PVC and Pod form your YAMLs?

Answer (score 0):

On prem.

kubelet logs has reoccurring error:speifying that the feature is not enabled
reconciler.go:248] operationExecutor.MountVolume failed (controllerAttachDetachEnabled true) for volume … (UniqueName: …) pod “…” (UID: “…”) : MapVolume.NewBlockVolumeMapper initialization failed for volume “…” (UniqueName: “…”) pod “…” (UID: “…”) : CSIBlockVolume feature not enabled

Comment: please edit your question. Don't post additional information as an answer.